# TypeScript / Playwright problem with passing arguments in the method

Tags: typescript, playwright

I have a problem with the "addTreeObject" method and its call in the test. I can't correctly pass the "projectSetup" arguments used in createFilledObject

The problem is probably with what I underlined in bold and I don't know how to solve it
How can I fix it to make it work?

```
 test(
    WithOrdinal`add tree object with properties`,
      const { addTreeObject } = ModifyProjectPage(page);
      **await addTreeObject(projectSetup.modbusPropertiesId, projectSetup.modbusPropertiesName);**
    }
  );
```

```
**addTreeObject: async (propertiesId: string, propertiesName: string, projectSetup: any,TemplateName: any, ProjectName: TreeName:any)** => {
      const { getByTestId } = deconstruct(page);
      const { createFilledObject } = ModifyProjectPage(page);
      await getByTestId(
        ProjectMenu.Edit.Properties.Object(treeId)
      ).hover();

      await getByTestId(
        ProjectMenu.Edit.Properties.AddAsTree(treeId)
      ).click();
      const object = await findObjectInTree(page, propertiesName);
      await object.click();
      **const addTreeObjectId = await createFilledObject(
        updatedSetupWithProperties,
        projectSetup.TemplateName,
        projectSetup.ProjectName,
        projectSetup.TreeName
       );**
      const nameInput = getByTestId(
        ProjectMenu.Edit.Properties.Settings.Name
      );

      await nameInput.clear();
      await nameInput.fill(treeId);

      return addTreeObjectId;
    }
```